# WCF - RESTful authentication - Always getting 400 or 401 HTTP response

Tags: wcf, authentication, rest, restful-authentication, webhttpbinding

I am using fiddler to generate a RESTful request to a TransportCredentialOnly(Basic) service.  if I include the "Authorization: Basic" line, I always get an error 400 bad request.  Otherwise, if I leave it out, I get the expected 401.

Usually when I see a 400 there is a stack trace, or some clue to help me debug it, but in this case nothing.  I am going in circles on this one.  The GUID+app_tracelog & app_tracelog don't seem to update or reveal anything, and in my service.config file I have

```
   <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
```

Which for most errors does yield a stack trace.  It would seem the auth subsystem is getting upset for some reason, but I have no clue why...

My request header in fiddler simply has Authorization: Basic [Base64 version of name;pass] and that's it.

Please advise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name and password should be separated by a colon, not a semi-colon.

Comment: I'm so glad you caught that.  That's what was causing my 400.  I expected to go through some big debugging chain, but no... thank you so much.